Sync a Ondrive folder (linked) to my onedrive on ubuntu 24
I follow this link: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2024/02/install-onedrive-ubuntu/
to install Ondrive through this: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:npreining:debian-ubuntu-onedrive&package=onedrive
This Ondrive third party only sync folder with me as owner, but not sync linked folder - others is owner (like Window behave). How to fix this?
I cannot use Gnome as this is Business account and block Gnome

You may find this Ubuntu Handbook article of some help

Follow the steps in this article to use OneDrive with 24.04. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/set-up-onedrive-file-access-in-ubuntu

@graham I use exactly that link, method 2

@Apollo18 I cannot use Gnome as this is Business account and block Gnome

Please read the client documentation: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/tree/master/docs
What account 'type' are you using? Personal ? Business ? SharePoint ?
You must configure the client to sync based on your account type.

@abrauegg My account is Business, Could you share the direct link to the guide? I go to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/install.md , then https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/onedrive and https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/arm64/onedrive/download, dont know how to do next, no downloadable link

You are following the wrong documentation - please read the install document more carefully
